# Adjust font size dynamically in a FlatList in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Before I begin trying to build something I want to check my strategy.

I think the best way to define what I would like to achieve is to build a component using a FlatList that adjusts fontSize dynamically based on the size of the View (or other more appropriately defined size limiting area) in which it is being displayed.

For example, let's say I want a FlatList of items (of data returned from an API call) that displays full-screen on Screen 1 of my app, but in a small corner of Screen 2 of my app.  Here's a quick mock of the behavior I would want:

[image]

It seems like the alignment of items, flex, other styles could be written so that the proportions/positions stay the same regardless of parent view in which the FlatList is displayed, so I might only have to adjust fontSize.

Can this behavior be achieved using a FlatList and a reference to a dynamic fontSize?  If so, where should the "awareness" of the parent View be stored/passed?

I'm looking for general input as to how to achieve this simply, with or without FlatList.  I like using FlatList because of how well it works off the shelf for my simple tasks.  Hopefully I'm not trying to make it do something it cant.

Thanks!

Comment: So as you scroll down, at some point you want to change the size of the flatlist? I think the component which has the responsibility of doing that should also have the responsibility of determining the new scale factor (or width & font size) and send it down the children.